# Width / Height unit for iText to create Online Editor

Tags: browser, height, width, itext

currently I´m working on a browser based Document editor.
I want to create different outputPanel. Each outputPanel has a size (height, widht, padding...).

Currently  I save all this sizes in px (pixel) (it´s the HTML code).

If I create the PDF with iText I want to create this with the saved sizes. For example:

height: 320px
width: 100px;

Now my question is this possible what I mean?
Or should I recalculate the saved sizes into a other format?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What is the question? *Is this possible what I mean* supposes that we know what you mean. Are you saying that you don't know the measurement system in PDF? If so, please read section 3.4.2.3 entitled "The measurement unit" in "The ABC of PDF": http://itextpdf.com/learn

Comment: I want to use the margin from a HTML. I have somethin like this: <html><head></head><body><div style="border-width: 413.0px; position: absolute; top: 221.0px; left: 62.0px; height: 30.0px;"> Test </div></body></html> But the margin of the <div> is not correct. Is it everytime the same margin.